# Changing href on website but clicking still links to old website

Tags: javascript, html, dom, href

I changed the href of the home button on LinkedIn website to redirect to another link, such as google. When I hover over the home button, it shows the new link, yet when I click on it the webpage refreshes and goes to the LinkedIn home page. Does anyone know why this happens? This is the code I am using in my JavaScript file to change the link.

`document.getElementById("global-nav").querySelector("a[href='/feed/']").setAttribute("href","https://www.google.com/");`

Comment: you need to prefix with slashes or http, like `"//www.google.com/"` or `"https://www.google.com/"`

Comment: even with the https:// it still links back to the homepage. If I set it to another path, such as "/notifications" (the notifications tab) it will still go to the homepage as well.

Comment: Any part of the html codes containing the anchor? Try to see if the href attribute is not changing too on click.

Comment: Did you found any solution to this? I'm getting the same.